# panning and zooming multiple images with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have multiple images that I want to fade and zoompan for each image but when I do what others have said, the first image works perfect and the second is black. I want to have 25 images and the same thing occurs with every image black except the first one. I am sure I am missing something elementary. Please help.

```
ffmpeg -r .1 -i image_1.jpg -i image_2.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=4.5:d=0.5"  -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using making a complex filtergraph similar to the following

```
-filter_complex "[0:v] panzoom, fadeout [scene1]; [1:v] panzoom, fadeout [scene2]; [scene1][scene2] concat=n=2 [output]" -map "output" output.mp4
```

Comment: You should separate your commands from your commentary with proper formatting. Click the question mark icon in the top right of the text box for Markdown Editing Help.